# Reading the Data of a Highlighted Jtable Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with rows of Data

I have this event that listen every time a row got mouse clicked

```
private void tablePOMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    try {
        int row1 = tablePO.getSelectedRow();
    cellA = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 0).toString();
    cellB = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 1).toString();
    cellC = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 2).toString();
    cellD= tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 3).toString();
    cellE = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 4).toString();
    cellF = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 5).toString();
    cellG = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 6).toString();
    cellH = tablePO.getValueAt(row1, 7).toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

variable cellA-H are all Strings.

its working good, but now I want to change it, I dont want the user to have the need to use the mouse, so instead, I want the user just select the row with using either UP/DOWN arrow to navigate the rows and put the selected row under the highlight, but I have no Idea how I am able to achieve it, reading the data from highlighted/selected row by using the UP/DOWN Keys (Not by pointing the row with mouse click).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ListSelectionListener` to the table.

An event will be generated whenever the row selection changes whether you use the mouse or the keyboard.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I am a slow learner, I am finding out how to implement it on my GUI generated JTable, Thnks by the way.